# React native how to Mutate the array inside object?

Tags: react-native

Response I am getting from API-

```
  {
  On: false
  Over: false
  Line: 10
  Point: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  }
```

This response i am using inside my component where i am using Point array and requirement is user can delete and index object inside array -
For Ex-

```
  {
  On: false
  Over: false
  Line: 10
  Point: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  }
```

Now this complete object i need to send via actions and update the Prop in reducer.
What i did -

```
 const [completeObject, setCompleteObject] = useState(props.completeObject);//{
                                                                    Enabled: false
                                                                    Over: false
                                                                    Line: 10
                                                                    Point: (5) [{…}, 
                                                                                  
                                                                 {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
                                                                }

const [Point, setPoint] = useState(props.completeObject.Point));//Point: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
const getUpdatedArray = selectedId => {
 let newArrayList = [];
 if (selectedId !== 0) {
 newArrayList = Point.filter((_, i) => i !== selectedId);
}
return newArrayList;
};

const OptionSelected = selectedId => {
 let newArrayList =   getUpdatedArray(selectedId);
 completeObject.Point = newArrayList;
 props.upadteArray(completeObject);//action dispatch

};
```

this gives error for me ,how can we update the array delete and add both and send to props please let me know this small thing is taking lot of time for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up with state naming. Try to refactor into this:

```
const [completeObject, setCompleteObject] = useState(props.completeObject);
const [Point, setPoint] = useState(props.completeObject.Point));

const getUpdatedArray = selectedId => {
  let newArrayList = [];
  if (selectedId !== 0) {
    newArrayList = Point.filter((_, i) => i !== selectedId);
  }

  return newArrayList;
};

const OptionSelected = selectedId => {
  let newArrayList = getUpdatedArray(selectedId);
  completeObject.Point = newArrayList;
  props.upadteArray(completeObject);
};
```

Comment: No thats not the issue this is just  a demo kind of code ,Actual code i cannot display its huge but state names i am using correct only .

Comment: Your code is error because you try accessing state setter property which doesn't exist. Notice the 'completeObject' part.

Comment: Hmm i got it now in reducer its updating but when i am deleting 1 point that is not reflect change but once i am navigating its reflecting .

Comment: If you want to get real-time changes after updating state, use `useEffect` and put the state inside that useEffect's dependency array.

Comment: I updated that issue , useEffect i tried may be i have not refreshed the code ,ohk ill try that again

Comment: I don't see what exactly the error is. You can copy paste the error message.

Comment: I don't see what exactly the error is. You can copy paste the error message.